# Sampling a probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, matlab, sampling

An actuary is using the following model for the proportion of settled claims
after time $t$: The proportion is $X$ where

$$P(X \leq x) = x^te^{t(1-x)}$$

Time is measured in small units. This is not a stochastic processes model;
the actuary is just modeling the marginal distribution of the proportion of
settled claims at a fixed time. Generate samples from the distribution of
$X$ for various values of $t$.

Continuing form the previous question, a mathematician discovered that the
random variable $Z = t(\log(X))^2$ is approximately exponentially distributed
with mean $2$ for large values of $t$. She did that by calculating the limit of
$P(Z > z)$ as $t \to \infty$. The actuary was sceptical about the approximation
overall and in particular, she claimed that the approximation was performing especially badly for large values of $Z$ (corresponding to small values of $X$).
Investigate all arguments using a sample generated in the previous question
and suggest an improvement by choosing a different approximating distribution.

I think writing a Matlab code is the way to go about with this problem. But I am not very well versed with Matlab to understand how to extract a sample and what the range of $t$ should be for the first part of the problem.

Comment: What is (are) your question(s)?

Comment: @NN2 my main question is to generate samples from the distribution of X for different values of t. I have been trying to write a Matlab code but I don't think I understand how to do it correctly. Say I have a large value of t, how do I generate x from it?

Comment: Hint: The question by itself is not difficult. It's complicated because it is ill-posed. In order to generate $X$, it suffice to find the inverse function $F^{-1}_X(y)$ from the equation $y = x^t \exp(t(1-x))$ (in order words, find $x$ in function of $y$) and then the sample can be obtained from $F^{-1}_X(U)$ where $U$ is a uniform random variable in $(0,1)$. But because there is no closed-form expression for the solution $y = x^t \exp(t(1-x))$ so we need to find approximative root for different value of $t$.

Comment: @NN2 I still don't get it. I understand that I need to approximate t by myself, but how do I get x if I don't have y? How and what exactly do I sample on? Maybe you could write an answer (if you don't mind) as I am having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: I guess you know this method for generating a sample from a known CDF  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Intuition

(in the question, the CDF is $F(x) = x^t \exp(t(1-x))$ ). The objective is to find the inverse CDF: find $x$ in function of $y$ from the equation (*) $ x^t \exp(t(1-x)) = y $. All problems are about to solve the equation (*) for different values of $t$ (by approximation, of course).